# How does git push handle a backlog

Tags: git, hook, push

I'm looking into setting up a distributed deployment of git servers.  I realize this is something git does by default but in this case said servers would act as a single source of truth with all of the assistance provided by centralized support.

Currently our code base and number of developers using the server is small ( a few hundred ) but once deployed I expect at least one thousand users to adopt along with their automated builds.  When this happens I expect that there will be a multi-fold increase in the number of pushes to the centrally supported git servers which will result in added pushes out to the other centrally supported git servers.

To limit the chances of a push storm caused by all of these servers pushing changes to each other I was planning to go with a standard hub spoke architecture where one or two servers would act as master servers, receiving pushes from spoke servers and pushing those changes back out to the other spokes.

My problem arises when I start to consider the impact of multiple pushes from globally located spoke servers backing up on the hub.  I have attempted to simulate this situation in my lab and from what I've seen the push process just hangs out waiting for the process in front of it to complete.   In a small deployment this works just fine.  However, when you throw build automation into the works commit / push activity can increase exponentially.   If I decided to create a post-receive hook that handled these pushes on a per client push basis I could foresee a situation where these processes could get backed up on the client servers waiting for the hub to receive the changes.

My questions are:

Are my concerns valid?  Will these processes gum up the works by hanging out until they are received by the hub?  Clients would be unaware of this state because the push processes would be forked off of the original reception.  However, they would see that changes would be delayed in appearing on the other remote servers.

If these processes will fail,  do they fail based on the wait interval for sshd or does git itself have a method of specifying a wait interval?

Other than monitoring the system processes or wrapping the push command to track its time to completion, is there a way to detect this operation backlog, or for that matter a hung receive condition on the master server?

Can you anyone point me towards some threads or articles dealing with this subject?

Worst case, a push using a timed interval could be used for each repository in place of a hook based push but I would like to keep things as free flowing and fast as possible so a hook based push would be preferred.

Comment: I assume from your mention of sshd that you're pushing via ssh?

Comment: Yes ssh is used for push / pull / clone operations

Comment: I feel that I've answered your main questions; particularly I've explained that pushes do not wait for a previous one to finish, which makes most of your questions irrelevant. You will only have problems if you are trying to support more pushes than your network can handle, and that's not really a Git question. I'm adding a tiny bit in my answer to address the size of push and fetch operations in case it's necessary. But network capacity planning isn't really on topic for this site - try [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com) if you have questions about it.

Answer (score 2):

Are you actually looking at a push volume so high it can DoS a server? I'm not entirely convinced from your question.

Pushes work like this:

- The local side talks to the remote side a bit, enough to figure out what objects it needs to transfer.
- The local side packs up all the necessary objects into a packfile
- The local side transfers the packfile to the remote, where it's stored under a temporary filename
- The packfile is renamed to a real filename once transfer is complete.
- The repository attempts to update refs as requested (e.g. point the master branch to the newly pushed commit for it)

*The transfers can happen in parallel.* So all you really have to worry about is whether you have enough network capacity to sustain all the pushes, and I doubt that's an issue. Pushes and fetches are very small. They only transfer the objects that are necessary (nothing that's already on the other side), and they delta-compress the contents based on objects that the other side already has, so the size is proportional to the size of the *diff* the transferred commits represent. If you can't handle transferring that much data, then I'm not sure that *any* distributed source control system could ever work for you.

That said, you can still run into issues if two people manage to push to the same branch at the same time, more likely, if one person thinks they're up to date and can push, then before they manage to push, someone else pushes, so the first developer has to pull before pushing. These are very real issues, but the way to deal with them is **not** by distributing your repository. It's by adopting a workflow that doesn't avoids that situation entirely.

First of all, if you actually are looking at a thousand developers, they're probably not all working on something in the same repository, right? And if they are... you probably want to split it up. If things need to be tied together at some high level, have a look at submodules. This is how, for example, the Linux kernel source is stored. There are a lot of bits, each in their own submodule, which are then part of a parent repository. Not many people need to mess with the parent repository; they just deal with the repo for the submodule they're working on, and not too many people are working on that. You *really* don't want to be in the situation of having a monolithic repository representing 10M lines of code.

Now, if after splitting up, you want to go further to reduce problems to do with many people trying to push to one branch, you probably want to just put a stop to that. Let an integrator (or a few) push to the main branches, and have everyone else just push to their own branches, which the integrator can merge. There are many, many variations on that, but you get the idea.

Finally, if you can avoid it, try not to do the hub/spoke thing. Large open source projects are successfully hosted from single repositories, so it seems likely that it'll work for you too. Remember that most operations are incremental (push/fetch), not total (clone), so they don't transfer a ton of data. If bandwidth is a concern, you will again be aided by splitting up the repositories properly; that'll reduce the amount of data to be transferred.

Comment: My questions are based off of past experiences with SVN and ClearCase.  To answer some of your questions.  Development would be spread widely across multiple repositories so having a large number of actual developers hitting one repository is not likely.  What is more likely and what I have seen in the past is Group X preforming automated builds for multiple components and sub components. These builds fire when changes are detected in their local working copy / repo and can fire in sequence or simultaneously. Creating a simulated load much higher than the actual user count.

Comment: If the builds are based off of their local repository, then why is load on a central server a problem?

Comment: The reason for wanting to track push operations is to minimize their impact on server operation.  By the sounds of things the cost of each operation is low which is what I suspected in my testing.  However, when you're looking at an existing 50 repos and likely 100's of future repos generating these operations across a global infrastructure even these small operations could add up.  I'm looking for a way to make sure the centrally supported repositories stay in sync while simultaneously monitoring these small operations for bad behavior (hung state, huge update, failed update etc).

Comment: The disk storage is SAN.  The network back plane is 10 GB.  Of course standard caveats apply - not all of the network bandwidth is available, available WAN bandwidth is likely much less and the SAN is not dedicated to just Git so your daily / hourly mileage will vary.  I need to make sure that Git is being a considerate neighbor when utilizing these resources.

Comment: Hosting from a single repository is the ideal from an admin viewpoint I agree. However, latency for international users is painful.  Large pulls that take minutes locally require substantially more time when pulling internationally.  We need to limit this latency. More servers solve this problem but cause a new one. With X servers, Y repos, Z users and allowing all of the servers to talk to each other simultaneously could get quite messy.  The higher X gets, the greater the mess.  Hub spoke allows me to limit the cross talk between servers.  Is there a reason Git shouldn't be synced this way?

Comment: I'm not really getting less confused here. Your chief concern about high usage seems to be due to automated builds, which you say are based off of local repositories, but you're asking about pushing. So... there's a build framework which automatically detects whenever someone commits in a local repo, then pushes to a central repo to perform the build? And then it's propagated everywhere, regardless of whether the developer wanted to publish that commit?

Comment: It's perfectly fine to have mirrored central repositories. But if every single commit made by every single developer is immediately pushed to them, you might not have a good workflow.

Comment: A 1:1 commit to push ratio would defeat the appeal of Git yes.  I would discourage groups that did such a thing.  Ignore the automated builds for now.  That was one example of a higher load condition we typically see.  There are multiple groups that use Hudson / Jenkins to monitor the state of the central repo so when a change is pushed to that repo the build framework will automatically pull the changes a start a build.  In some cases one change can cause many builds to fire simultaneously which increases load for the server.

Comment: To anticipate this condition (I know it's coming for git)  I need to minimize the impact of any other operations that utilize network or disk resources.  I.E. syncs between servers

Comment: Part of my goal for minimizing the impact is detecting any bad behavior in the syncs or at least limiting its impact by increasing the intervals between syncs.